# Edit info.plist file using applescript/terminal

Tags: shell, daemon, info.plist

How can I add

```
<key>NSUIElement</key>
<string>1</string>
```

to an info.plist file using applescript or terminal? Or is there another way to automatically make an application into a daemon?

Answer (score 0):

`plutil -convert text /Info.plist/file/location` will convert the file from binary format to text in-place, from which you can then add your new key and value. The command has other options, but I couldn't figure out how to get `-insert` or `-replace` working on Mavericks. If someone does, feel free to edit this answer or leave a comment and I'll edit it.

Comment: So exactly what would be the code for adding

<key>NSUIElement</key>
<string>1</string>

Comment: Add it in using your text editor... plutil converts it to text and then you can use TextEdit or whatever to add it in.

Comment: and afterwards I just add the defaults write command once i convert it?